# How to show a DIV when sitting a mouse on it using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, html

How to show a DIV when the mouse is over another div (I have multiple divs, when I have the mouse over one of them I want a "info" window appears ) , and keeping it appear until the mouse it moved out of the area of the div.

I want the din to appear in the position of the mouse ?

Comment: Can you PLEASE clarify your question?

Comment: sorry, it's a mistake. can you find it now ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "sitting a mouse on it"?

Comment: How is the DIV hidden? With css?

Comment: Using what exactly? `display: none;` or `visibility: hidden;`?

Comment: Adham, you're getting irritated (or what I can interpret as irritated) by people asking questions about your question. If you had made your question clearer in the first place, we wouldn't have to leave so many comments.

Comment: really sorry, please check the updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the div is hidden, mouseover would not fire to make it visible. So you can play with background color instead. Something like [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sFLvX/).

Here is the code:

**Markup**

```
Some text here.
<div id="area"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#area {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 130px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("#area").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
$("#area").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'transparent');
});
```

Comment: thanks . I have already posted this http://jsfiddle.net/sFLvX/1/ in the spot of you answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/). They have done most of the work for you, leaving you to just styling and formatting contents.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by myself !

Check the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sFLvX/)